# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined Using Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using this [Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) And after I build the project and run it I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

I look at the solutions in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352394/webpack-cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined) but deleting the package-lock.json and node_modules and then running npm install doesn't work. I also made sure I'm running the latest version of node. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Electron. Search your code for `.match`. You are trying to use this function on `undefined` value, e.g.: `someVariable.match(...)` where `someVariable` is undefined

Comment: I searched my code for .match and nothing shows up. But in the dev tools there is a .match, but I have no idea where the code comes from- so I assumed it was from electron. Maybe it has to deal with an npm package

Comment: Show us the full error trace (click on the error in the console)

Comment: I packaged my code and searched for .match and there appears to be .match's in the dist_electron folder(The packaged electron folder) So I think it has to do with the way it's packaged.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at u (chunk-vendors.f76ff44a.js:27)
    at m (chunk-vendors.f76ff44a.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chunk-vendors.f76ff44a.js:1)
    at Object.0da7 (chunk-vendors.f76ff44a.js:1)
    at r (app.6d09f96e.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chunk-vendors.f76ff44a.js:46)
    at Object.ce7a (chunk-vendors.f76ff44a.js:46)
    at r (app.6d09f96e.js:1)
    at Object.305d (chunk-vendors.f76ff44a.js:15)
    at r (app.6d09f96e.js:1)